# Mercurial SQL and Windows Command

Tags: sql, mercurial, cmd

Example of the contents I require a .cmd to contain

```
    mkdir Output
    sqlcmd -S serverName -d dbName -E -i "FILE LOCATION HERE" -o Output\Message.log
    sqlcmd -S serverName -d dbName -E -i "FILE LOCATION HERE" >> Output\Messages.log
    .
    .
    .
    pause
```

Specifics: I have a SQL repo and need to generate a code that will take all changes from last revision to this revisionand output the above example.

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL repo"? A repository with SQL scripts? Exactly how Mercurial is involved, and what does it have to do with the batch script?

Comment: A repository of SQL scripts. Mercurial is what I am using to track changes to the scripts. I want a script that takes in the mercurial revision numbers. If any script has been changed then it should appear in the batch

Comment: What have you done to attempt to find a solution? Show that you've put *some* effort into this, instead of asking people here to hand you an answer.

Comment: You expect me to show you 2 hours of background work. If you don't like it don't answer

Comment: those who want to help can, those who don't want to help don't have to

Answer (score 1):

As far as Mercurial is concerned,

```
hg status -I re:.*\.sql$ -am --rev 3:7
```

will give the relation of all files with `.sql` extension added or modified after changeset 3 and up to changeset 7. You can then massage the output into the desired script with your favourite text processing tools.

N.B.: Blindly running all modified SQL scripts, specially if you intend to use this procedure more than once, seems rather dangerous, unless you are sure all the operations are idempotent.